# Download PDF through browser authentication with javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, browser

I understand that I can do browser authentication with Javascript, and then grab, say, an XML file with that javascript. My use case is a bit different though: There's a link on a webpage to a PDF on a different server. That server does browser authentication. The username and password are NOT secrets, in fact right now, we publish the link like this:

"Download PDF (use guest/guest as username/password)".

What I need: the user clicks the link, but does NOT have to fill in the username/pass, because we see many users getting confused by this (in usability tests).

We do not have access to the other server where the PDF is hosted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the link like this: http://gast:gast@mis.vlaanderen.be/cognos7/metadata/mp_v_i_im_020_e100_az_algemeen_overzicht.pdf

Comment: This won't work in IE7 (and possibly IE6) - they removed support for it.

Answer (score 0):

This URL is a test case: http://mis.vlaanderen.be/cognos7/metadata/mp_v_i_im_020_e100_az_algemeen_overzicht.pdf

The username is "gast", the password is "gast" (as it says in the authentication box).

If you can embed that in a page in a link, and make it open without triggering the browser authentication box, you're my hero :)

Answer (score 0):

http://gast:gast@domain.com/file.pdf